# Smart contract in VS Code not connecting to Ethereum Test Network

Tags: solidity, metamask, visual-studio-code

Language: Solidity

I wrote a smart contract in VS Code editor and wanted to test it with a MetaMask Ethereum Test Network.

However, I keep getting chainId address mismatch because the contract keeps connecting to my Ethereum Mainnet instead of a Test Network.

When I change my chainId to that of the Ethereum Mainnet, the error message changes to insufficient fund (I have no fund in the Mainnet address).

I've selected the Test Network (having test Ether) I wanted to use in MetaMask, yet, the smart contract isn't connecting to my Test Network but to the Ethereum Mainnet.

This is happening in VS Code.

Here's the code:

```
const ethers = require("ethers");
const fs = require("fs-extra");
require("dotenv").config();

async function main() {
  const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(process.env.RPC_URL);
  const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY, provider);

  const abi = fs.readFileSync("./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.abi", "utf8");
  const binary = fs.readFileSync(
    "./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.bin",
    "utf8"
  );
  const contractFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, binary, wallet);
  console.log("Deploying please wait...");
  const nonce = await wallet.getTransactionCount();
  const tx = {
    nonce: nonce,
    gasPrice: 20000000000,
    gasLimit: 1000000,
    to: null,
    value: 0,
    data: "0x60....",
    chainId: 5,
  };

  const sentTxResponse = await wallet.sendTransaction(tx);
  await sentTxResponse.wait(1);
  console.log(sentTxResponse);

  const contract = await contractFactory.deploy();
  await contract.deployTransaction.wait(1);
  console.log(`Contract Address: ${contract.address}`);

  const currentFavoriteNumber = await contract.retrieve();
  console.log(`Current favorite number: ${currentFavoriteNumber.toString()}`);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Here's the error message:

```
Deploying please wait...
Error: chainId address mismatch (argument="transaction", value={"nonce":0,"gasPrice":20000000000,"gasLimit":1000000,"to":null,"value":0,"data":"0x608060405234801561001057600080fd5b50610771806100206000396000f3fe608060405234801561001057600080fd5b50600436106100575760003560e01c80632e64cec11461005c5780636057361d1461007a5780636f760f41146100965780638bab8dd5146100b25780639e7a13ad146100e2575b600080fd5b610064610113565b604051610071919061035c565b60405180910390f35b610094600480360381019061008f91906103b7565b61011c565b005b6100b060048036038101906100ab919061052a565b610126565b005b6100cc60048036038101906100c79190610586565b6101b6565b6040516100d9919061035c565b60405180910390f35b6100fc60048036038101906100f791906103b7565b6101e4565b60405161010a929190610657565b60405180910390f35b60008054905090565b8060008190555050565b6001604051806040016040528083815260200184815250908060018154018082558091505060019003906000526020600020906002020160009091909190915060008201518160000155602082015181600101908051906020019061018c9291906102a0565b505050806002836040516101a091906106c3565b9081526020016040518091039020819055505050565b6002818051602081018201805184825260208301602085012081835280955050505050506000915090505481565b600181815481106101f457600080fd5b906000526020600020906002020160009150905080600001549080600101805461021d90610709565b80601f016020809104026020016040519081016040528092919081815260200182805461024990610709565b80156102965780601f1061026b57610100808354040283529160200191610296565b820191906000526020600020905b81548152906001019060200180831161027957829003601f168201915b5050505050905082565b8280546102ac90610709565b90600052602060002090601f0160209004810192826102ce5760008555610315565b82601f106102e757805160ff1916838001178555610315565b82800160010185558215610315579182015b828111156103145782518255916020019190600101906102f9565b5b5090506103229190610326565b5090565b5b8082111561033f576000816000905550600101610327565b5090565b6000819050919050565b61035681610343565b82525050565b6000602082019050610371600083018461034d565b92915050565b6000604051905090565b600080fd5b600080fd5b61039481610343565b811461039f57600080fd5b50565b6000813590506103b18161038b565b92915050565b6000602082840312156103cd576103cc610381565b5b60006103db848285016103a2565b91505092915050565b600080fd5b600080fd5b6000601f19601f8301169050919050565b7f4e487b7100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600052604160045260246000fd5b610437826103ee565b810181811067ffffffffffffffff82111715610456576104556103ff565b5b80604052505050565b6000610469610377565b9050610475828261042e565b919050565b600067ffffffffffffffff821115610495576104946103ff565b5b61049e826103ee565b9050602081019050919050565b82818337600083830152505050565b60006104cd6104c88461047a565b61045f565b9050828152602081018484840111156104e9576104e86103e9565b5b6104f48482856104ab565b509392505050565b600082601f830112610511576105106103e4565b5b81356105218482602086016104ba565b91505092915050565b6000806040838503121561054157610540610381565b5b600083013567ffffffffffffffff81111561055f5761055e610386565b5b61056b858286016104fc565b925050602061057c858286016103a2565b9150509250929050565b60006020828403121561059c5761059b610381565b5b600082013567ffffffffffffffff8111156105ba576105b9610386565b5b6105c6848285016104fc565b91505092915050565b600081519050919050565b600082825260208201905092915050565b60005b838110156106095780820151818401526020810190506105ee565b83811115610618576000848401525b50505050565b6000610629826105cf565b61063381856105da565b93506106438185602086016105eb565b61064c816103ee565b840191505092915050565b600060408201905061066c600083018561034d565b818103602083015261067e818461061e565b90509392505050565b600081905092915050565b600061069d826105cf565b6106a78185610687565b93506106b78185602086016105eb565b80840191505092915050565b60006106cf8284610692565b915081905092915050565b7f4e487b7100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600052602260045260246000fd5b6000600282049050600182168061072157607f821691505b60208210811415610735576107346106da565b5b5091905056fea2646970667358221220b4b279c6549915a91447ef764641d09dfc9385a5d8f9e2c8a4dbe5612af1354364736f6c63430008080033","chainId":42}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abstract-signer/5.7.0)     
    at Logger.makeError (C:\Users\hp\Documents\Solidity Projects\Pat\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:238:21)
    at Logger.throwError (C:\Users\hp\Documents\Solidity Projects\Pat\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:247:20)
    at Logger.throwArgumentError (C:\Users\hp\Documents\Solidity Projects\Pat\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:250:21)
    at C:\Users\hp\Documents\Solidity Projects\Pat\node_modules\@ethersproject\abstract-signer\lib\index.js:380:44
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 5) {
  reason: 'chainId address mismatch',
  code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
  argument: 'transaction',
  value: {
    nonce: 0,
    gasPrice: 20000000000,
    gasLimit: 1000000,
    to: null,
    value: 0,
    data: '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',
    chainId: 42
  }
}
PS C:\Users\hp\Documents\Solidity Projects\Pat> node deploy.js
Deploying please wait...
Error: chainId address mismatch (argument="transaction", value={"nonce":0,"gasPrice":20000000000,"gasLimit":1000000,"to":null,"value":0,"data":"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","chainId":5}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abstract-signer/5.7.0)        
    at Logger.makeError (C:\Users\hp\Documents\Solidity Projects\Pat\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:238:21)
    at Logger.throwError (C:\Users\hp\Documents\Solidity Projects\Pat\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:247:20)
    at Logger.throwArgumentError (C:\Users\hp\Documents\Solidity Projects\Pat\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:250:21)
    at C:\Users\hp\Documents\Solidity Projects\Pat\node_modules\@ethersproject\abstract-signer\lib\index.js:380:44
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 5) {
  reason: 'chainId address mismatch',
  code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
  argument: 'transaction',
  value: {
    nonce: 0,
    gasPrice: 20000000000,
    gasLimit: 1000000,
    to: null,
    value: 0,
    data: '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',
    chainId: 5
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to show us how you deploy/interact your contract with the mainnet/testnet, e.g: using hardhat/truffle, what your config file looks like, etc.

Comment: what function are you trying to run? definitely need a bit more info

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is likely you are using the wrong RPC endpoint.

Comment: @Ismael, thanks a lot. You're right. I selected Mainnet Network in Alchemy RPC instead of Goerli while creating the app in Alchemy.